# Pandas to_sql changing datatype in Postgresql table

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have created a table using the flask db migrate method.

Below is how my model is

```
class MutualFundsDataTest(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    MF_Code = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    Scheme_Code_Direct = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    Scheme_Code_Regular = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    Sub_Category = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    Plan = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    AUM = db.Column(db.NUMERIC, nullable=True)
    Expense_Ratio = db.Column(db.NUMERIC, nullable=True)
    Time_Since_Inception = db.Column(db.NUMERIC, nullable=True)
    Exit_Load = db.Column(db.NUMERIC, nullable=True)
```

and I have another script that is responsible for inserting data into the database from an xlsx file. I have specified the datatype for each column which is consistent with the datatype from the above posted model.py file. All my columns should be either TEXT or NUMERIC type.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import types 

sql_types =  {"Name": types.TEXT(), "MF_Code" : types.TEXT(),"Scheme_Code_Direct" : types.TEXT(),"Scheme_Code_Regular" : types.TEXT(), "Sub_Category" : types.TEXT(), "Plan": types.TEXT(), "AUM" : types.NUMERIC(), "Expense_Ratio" : types.NUMERIC(), "Time_Since_Inception" : types.NUMERIC(), "Exit_Load" : types.NUMERIC()}

df = pd.read_excel('./path_to_xlxs', "sheet_name")

engine= create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost:port/database')
df.to_sql('mutual_funds_data_test', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype=sql_types)
```

But for some reason, pandas is changing the datatypes of the column in the Postgresql database Below is the screenshot of the column from the Postgresql after pandas has changed the column datatype.

Is there any way to force pandas not to change datatype? I am not sure why it is changing it as there is no error.  I am following this [Documentation1](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-data-types), [Documentation2](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

[image]

Comment: funny that read_excel does not exist as a tag, while read_csv does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column names in `sql_types` have underscores, which are not there in the screenshot. You need to rename your columns first to match the dictionary keys.
If you define the schema elsewhere, consider not using `if_exists="replace"`. This would have shown you the schema mismatch immediately.

Comment: This really helped me and solved my problem. I don't know, how I was. missing the underscore to make the column names consistent. Thank you very much.